# Trying to get equal height columns with expanding text whilst using overflow with CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, flexbox

Ok, I have this code I have done up here on how I need this solution to function:

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaOrGr?editors=110

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper row">
      <div class="box col-sm-4">
        <div class="cta-background">

        </div>
   <div class="rollover-wrap">
      <div class="details">
        some text
      </div>
      <div class="summary">
        fhdhjofsdhohfsohfsouhofuhufhoufdsh
        fskjoifhspofhdsohfdsohfohfsd
        fsdujhofhofdshofhohfds
        fdsolhfsdohfodshfohfdsohfosd
        fsdljhfdsouhfdsohhfso
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box col-sm-4">
        <div class="cta-background">

        </div>
<div class="rollover-wrap">
      <div class="details">
        some text
      </div>
      <div class="summary">
        fhdhjofsdhohfsohfsouhofuhufhoufdsh
        fskjoifhspofhdsohfdsohfohfsd
        fsdujhofhofdshofhohfds
        fdsolhfsdohfodshfohfdsohfosd
        fsdljhfdsouhfdsohhfso
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box col-sm-4">
        <div class="cta-background">

        </div>
<div class="rollover-wrap">
      <div class="details">
        some text
      </div>
      <div class="summary">
        fhdhjofsdhohfsohfsouhofuhufhoufdsh
        fskjoifhspofhdsohfdsohfohfsd
        fsdujhofhofdshofhohfds
        fdsolhfsdohfodshfohfdsohfosd
        fsdljhfdsouhfdsohhfso
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS / CSS:**

```
.wrapper {

  .box {

    position: relative;
  height: 340px;
  overflow: hidden;    
    margin-top: 10px;

    &:hover > .rollover-wrap {
      bottom: 260px;
    }    

    .cta-background {
      background-image: url('http://ideas.homelife.com.au/media/images/8/2/8/9/0/828947-1_ll.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      height: 260px;
    }

    .rollover-wrap {
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
      transition: 0.3s;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .details {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: gray;
      height: 80px;
    }

    .summary {
      height: 260px;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 15px;
      background-color: #E29222;
      z-index: 2;
    }

  }

}
```

This is working fine and is the effect I am wanting; however, I need to support the gray area being able to have *multiple lines* of text, and if one does, then the other adjacent gray sections should expand to the same height.

At the moment it uses fixed heights to assist with hiding and bringing in the transition on hover, but this hinders the ability for the gray area to expand. Even if it could expand, the other boxes need to match the height.

I have tried using `flexbox` and changing the html layout to no avail.

I don't mind if the image & summary sections have a fixed height, but the gray area needs to be able to expand to it's content.

Is there anyway to do what I want to do without JavaScript? If not, is there a clean way to do it with JavaScript/jQuery that doesn't have too much of a messy fallback?

Comment: For flexbox to be able to achieve that, you would need to have all of those boxes be children of the same parent element – and I doubt that you would end up with a structure that still reflects the meaning of the content appropriately. Using a small JS function that measures the maximum height, and sets it for all three boxes, might be the easiest solution – perhaps combined with a resize handler that modifies it when necessary if you need it to be responsive.

Comment: In JS you can calculate height of the gray container, then - height of the orange box = whole height - grey box height